# Indicator function of rationality

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $X: [0,1]\to \mathbb {R}$ be a function that maps every rational number in the interval $[0,1]$ to $0$, and every irrational number to $1$. Assume that the probability space where $X$ is defined is $([0,1],\mathcal{B}[0,1],\mathbb {P})$, where $\mathcal {B}[0,1]$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$, and $\mathbb {P}$ is the Lebesgue measure. Is $X$ a random variable (and why)? If it is, what are its distribution function and expectation? Does $X$ have a density function? Is $X$ discrete? First of all, I think $X$ is a random variable since $X^{-1}\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{0\},\{0,1\}\}\in \mathcal{B}[0,1]$. I wonder how to get its distribution function. It seems like it's a kind of indicator function. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of rational numbers has Lebesgue measure $0$. This implies that $X=1$ almost surely. Hence $X$ is discrete, it does not have a density and $EX=E1=1$.

Comment: So can I still say $X$ is a random variable if $X=1$ almost surely?

Comment: Certainly. Random variables can be constant with probability $1$. You have already verified that $X$ is a random variable. @Jiexiong687691

Comment: Thanks. And can I say that $X:([0,1],\mathcal {B}[0,1])\to (\{0,1\},\{\emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}\})$ and $X$ maps intervals to $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Yes, if you mean open intervals. If $x$ is rational number then $\{x\}$ is also considered an interval and $X$ maps this interval to $\{0\}$.